# How to prove that ($56n^2+106n+48)(\log(264n^2+200)) = Θ(^2\log n)$

Tags: algorithms, runtime-analysis, big-o-notation

I understand that essentially we have to prove that

$$c_1(n^2\log n)\le 
   (56n^2+106n+48)(\log(264n^2+200)) 
       \le c_2(n^2\log n)\,.$$

I am confused on how to simplify this further? And correctly find a c value.

Comment: This is a really basic exercise. What have you tried so far apart from applying the definition of $\Theta$?

Comment: I'm trying to learn the correct way to approach these problems. Basic for you, not for me lol.

Answer (score 2):

For all $n\geq 1$, $56n^2+106n+48> 56n^2> n^2$ and $\log (264n^2+200)> \log 264n^2>\log n$, so 
$$(56n^2+106n+48)\log(264n^2+200) > n^2\log n\,,$$
i.e., you can take $c_1=1$.

Also for all $n\geq 1$, $56n^2+106n+48\leq 56n^2+106n^2+48n^2 = 210n^2$ and, for all $n\geq 200$, $264n+200 < 265n$ so $\log(264n^2+200) < \log 265n^2 = 2\log n + \log 265$. For all $n\ge 265$, $2\log n + \log 265\leq 3\log n$.  Therefore, for all $n\geq 265$,
$$(56n^2+106n+48)\log(264n^2+200) < 630n^2\log n\,,$$
i.e., you can take $c_2=630$.

Comment: is there any method to choosing a c value or is it random?

Comment: I just showed you how to do it. I didn't try to come up with "good" values of $c_1$ and $c_2$, but any value will do, as long as it satisfies the inequalities.

Comment: You miss the square of $n$ in inequality in first line, but it does not matter as it is in $\log$ function.

Comment: @jaxa9831 Thanks! Now fixed.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thanks! But how did you get 630n^2 log n? (in the 2nd last line)

Comment: @lizzy_mber $210n^2\times 3\log n$.

Answer (score 0):

It's sometimes more convenient to work with the [limit definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations).

To prove the statement, you can break it down into proving that $f(n) = O(g(n))$ and that $f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$. In your case, it's straightforward to compute $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)/g(n)$. I believe that this will turn out to be a positive three-digit constant less than infinity and greater than zero, and we'll be done.

Answer (score 0):

$c_1 = 56$ works for all n.

Let n >= 265, then 200 <= $n^2$, $264n^2 + 200 <= n^3$,  the logarithm is less than 3 log n, $56n^2  + 106n + 48 <= 56n^2 + n^2 + n^2 = 58n^2$, so you can pick $c_2 = 58*3 = 174.